# Unreliable connection on USB-C to Ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, usb-c

I recently purchased a new Win10 64-bit laptop with no Ethernet port. I obtained a USB-C adapter with three USB-A ports and an Ethernet (RJ-45) port. I leave it connected most of the time. When I turn off the laptop and restart it, my network connection works well for a few minutes, then drops off (no internet). After I unplug and replug the Ethernet cable one or more times, my internet connection returns and stays on.

Another PC connected directly to the wired Ethernet hub (**without** the adapter) has no problems. Also, I can connect to the router via wifi with no problems.

(Configuration is coax cable -> cable modem -> Ethernet cable -> router -> Ethernet cable -> Ethernet hub -> Ethernet cable -> USB-C adapter -> laptop)

Does anyone know whether there is a fix for this?

Running Win10 64-bit Home v21H2 19044.1466 on an LG Gram 17Z90.

Using Uni adapter https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0871ZL9TG

Thanks!

Comment: In Device Manager, find the USB-C adapter (probably under Network adapters), right-click, Properties, Power Management tab, disable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", OK, and reboot.

Comment: Did you try the adapter with a different PC? I had quite a few with hardware defects. I ended up buying them from the better known brands mainly invested in network devices such as TP-Link, D-Link, etc (or one of the "more expensive ones"). In my experience they work much more reliable.

Comment: I can ask around for a PC with USB-C ports. I only have one.

Comment: @harrymc I don't see a "Power Management" tab under Properties for any of the devices I looked at in Device Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unset
"Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
in the Power Management tab if the device.

To restore the missing Power Management tab in Windows 10 21H2,
use the following
[advice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/power-management-tab-is-missing-in-device-manager/f84fe229-fb66-4aa1-a397-e9ac65f791e5):

You need to add the item `PlatformAoAcOverride` with value `0`
to the registry at key
`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power.

Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator and enter the following command:

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Or to remove:

```
reg delete "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power" /v PlatformAoAcOverride
```

Reboot for this to have effect.

Comment: I can give this a try when I get a chance. Could you address why this would help when the laptop has not gone to sleep or hibernation? In other words, I boot the PC from power off, then start to use it, and after using it for several minutes, the network connection stops working.

Comment: You might need to also [Disable Fast Startup](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10).

Comment: I disabled fast startup when I got the PC, and it remains off, but thanks for the idea. By the way, my problem is intermittent (it doesn't happen every time).

Comment: Okay, I modified the registry and unset "Allow the computer to turn off ...." Now I'll have to wait and see what happens. I'll let you know.

Comment: Mixed results. My first effort was to prevent Windows from turning off the Ethernet device itself (under Network Adapters). This did not work.

So then I changed the power setting for the USB controller devices associated with the USB-C adapter. There were two: A "Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub" and "Generic USB Hub." It didn't seem to matter which one, but preventing Windows from turning it off fixed the problem.

I'm not certain, but it seems like a side-effect is that Windows never turns off ANY of the USB devices, including the mouse attached to a built-in USB-A port. It always stays lit.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into generic dropouts with HP laptops requiring usbc or otherwise to ethernet port.  The problem is the HP Connection optimizer.  Repair the installation or remove it. This solved the problem of failed connections after 5 minutes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Device Manager, Network adapters, Realtek USB GbE Family Controller -> disable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power",

Finally my Steam Deck is consistently  Ethernet Wired!

[Disable Power Managements to save power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8vA9.png)

Comment: This answer does not add further information and merely repeats a more complete answer already posted. When posting an answer later, please make sure that the answer you're giving is not simply repeating an answer already given.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).